# Setup Apache to use a remotely hosted configuation file?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have several cloud hosted servers with identical configurations. I want them all to share a httpd.conf file that I can edit in one place. Is there a way to setup apache to use a remote mapped file? Or some other service that could provide this same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achive this is use shared filesystem . you can use sshfs to make remote files or directories available to you locally

You need to install sshfs on one of the machine and use follwing command

**Commands :-**

sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/remote_conf_directory

sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions root@remoteIP:/etc/apache2/
 /etc/apache2/remote_conf_directory

now the configuration will be available to you , now either replace configure directory path in local machine apache configuration or overwrite it

I hope you will get an idea to start from this

Comment: Or just use NFS for Unix systems or smb for windiws ones. The more interesting part of the question is triggering reloads

Comment: What about scalability?  I sometimes have issues with sshfs on a local network with moderate traffic.  For small numbers of systems this may work but for a large number of systems scalability and performance will become an issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually,you're approaching problem from different and possibly  wrong end.

Let's redefine it.

1) We want to maintain a single configuration file to be used by multiple apache instances scattered  across cloud.

2) All instance should detect the changes in config file and should be restarted automatically .

Now this is the exactly kind of requirement ansible or any other config management tools are designed for.  You can write a playbook for ansible which will

1) Check md5 sum of config file locally and and config file remotely

2) Push the file to all the hosts if contents of local files are changed.

3) Restart the httpd servuce in cloud.

4) Notify/log the failure if it is unabke to connect to any cloud instance.

Finally,put this all in cron and forget that you ever need to worry about configuration management. Just updatethe hosts inventory and ansible will take care of rest of the things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a configuration management tool like [Salt](https://saltstack.com) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io).  This [tutorial](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/) should cover what you need to coordinate several servers.